# node spawn_child to use different node version

Tags: node.js, child-process, nvm

I have a node script which runs Webdriver tests. I am using following code

```js
const procInfo = child_process.spawn('wdio',
    0,
    pathModule.join(downloadDir, 'node_modules', '.bin', IsWin32 ? 'wdio.cmd' : 'wdio'),
    args, {
    cwd: downloadDir,
    env: env,
    detached: !IsWin32,
    stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', 'pipe']
  });
```

I have nvm installed as well. My main process is started with node v14. I want to let user decide from the interface which node version they want to run.

How can I make child_process to use different version of node like v10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by changing the path in environment

Below is complete solution

```js
const IsWin32 = process.platform === 'win32';


const env = process.env;
  if(IsWin32)
    env.Path = '/home/testable/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/bin' + pathModule.delimiter + env.Path;
  else
    env.PATH = 'C:\\ProgramData\\nvm\\v10.24.1\\' + pathModule.delimiter + env.PATH;

const procInfo = child_process.spawn('wdio',
    0,
    pathModule.join(downloadDir, 'node_modules', '.bin', IsWin32 ? 'wdio.cmd' : 'wdio'),
    args, {
    cwd: downloadDir,
    env: env,
    detached: !IsWin32,
    stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', 'pipe']
  });
```